# Referencing value pulled from scanf

Tags: c

I am very unsure how to word this question as it is very confusing. I am writing a program with 2 functions so far as shown below:

```
int main(){
     int a;

     printf(.....)
     scanf(%d,&a)

int prime(.....){
      int a;

       if(....){
           if(....){
              printf(.....)
       }}`//More to code after this but that is irrelevant`
```

So what I would like to do is use the value taken from the `scanf` function and then use that value in the several if and other statements within the `prime` function. How do I 'state' this value in the `prime` function? I have attempted to find other topics similar to this but have struggled as I am unaware of what to search. Sorry if this question has been asked before.

Comment: Read the value in `main` and pass the read value as an argument to `prime`. What exactly is your issue? You haven't actually asked a question. You have said what you would like to do but not why you can't do it.

Comment: I am just confused on how to do that exactly like what to type, I am very new to all this but am trying my best to learn it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is a very basic question so here's a very basic answer. But really, recommend you to go back and work systematically through a C text book or tutorial rather than try to learn piecemeal like this.

```
int prime (int a)
{
    /* do stuff with a */
    printf("main gave me this a value: %d\n", a);

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int a;
    int rval;

    rval = scanf("%d", &a);
    if (rval == 1) {
        prime(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: Testing the return value of `scanf()`! Very nice!

Comment: Okay thank you, and I am sorry for asking such a silly question. Would you happen to know of any good C books that you would recommend reading through?